# C: Why does this server / client setup only work inside one computer?

Tags: c, networking, server, client

I'm new to networks and I'm wondering why this [TCP Server-Client implementation in C](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/tcp-server-client-implementation-in-c/)
 only works on one computer? (1)

I mean I have to open one terminal for the server program and another one for the client program. But why this doesn't work between computers? Starting the server program on one computer and the client program on another computer.

How we need to modify the code to work between computers? (2)

And what are great resources to start on the whole topic? (3)

Comment: Please, do not post links.  Rather copy/paste the code into the question

Comment: regarding: `while ((buff[n++] = getchar()) != '\n')`  1) the function: `getchar()` returns a `int`, not a `char`,  Although you can cast it to `char`.   2) this statement allows the user to overrun the input buffer.   Suggest: `while ( n < MAX && (buff[n++] = (char)getchar()) != '\n')`  Also, should be checking for EOF

Comment: regarding: `close(sockfd);`   There is no prototype for the function: `close()`.  To fix that, need to have the statement: `#include <unistd.h>`

Comment: regarding: `int sockfd, connfd, len;` and `connfd = accept(sockfd, (SA*)&cli, &len);` they syntax for `accept()` is: `int accept(int sockfd, struct sockaddr *addr, socklen_t *addrlen);`  where `socklen_t` should be used (an unsigned value) rather than the current `len` which is a `int`, I.E. a signed value

Comment: when compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings.  ( for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11` )  Note: other compilers use different options to produce the same results

Comment: OT: regarding: `printf("socket creation failed...\n"); 
        exit(0);`  1) this is a failure, so (typically) should call: `exit( EXIT_FAILURE );` rather than returning 0   2) error messages should be output to `stderr`, not `stdout` and when the error indication is from a C library function, should call `perror( "socket failed" );` so both that error message and the reason the system thinks the error occurred are output to `stderr`.  Similar considerations exist for handling the other errors

Comment: regarding; `while ( n<MAX && (buff[n++] = (char)getchar()) != '\n') 
            ; 
  
        // and send that buffer to client 
        write(sockfd, buff, sizeof(buff));`  You really only want to write the data input by the user, not all the following trash in the buffer.  Therefore, suggest:  `while ( n<MAX && (buff[n++] = (char)getchar()) != '\n') ;  buff[n] = '\0';
  
        // and send that buffer to client 
        write(sockfd, buff, strlen(buff));`  Notice the NUL termination of the buffer and use of `strlen()` to send the proper number of characters.

Comment: regarding: `write(sockfd, buff, sizeof(buff));` the function: `write()` 'can' result in less bytes sent than requested.  so should be checking the returned value and using a sliding window to retry when necessary.

Comment: regarding: `read(sockfd, buff, sizeof(buff));`  the function: `read()` can return `0` meaning the other end of the connection hungup.  can return `<0` meaning an error occurred.  The code should be checking for these things rather than assuming that call to `read()` was successful.

Comment: regarding: `printf("From client: %s\t To client : ", buff);`  The call to `read()` does not NUL terminate the input, so must use the returned value from `read()` to insert a NUL byte at the correct location in the buffer, before trying to print the buffer

Comment: the server failed to close the `connfd`

Comment: the client calls `close()` but is missing the statement: `#include <unistd.h>`

Comment: the client code has most of the same problems as the server code.  You need to fix those problems

Comment: wow @user3629249 thank you for adding this. Seems the site doesn't really care about these, maybe they also just wanted it to work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will work on other computers.
Just ensure you do the followings:

1. Two computer be on a network and see each other with PING
2. Change `127.0.0.1` in client program with the IP of the server machine
3. Check listening ports with `netstat` of server machine and Make sure the port 8080 is in Listening mode
4. Make sure there is no firewall in server machine, you can use `telnet` in client machine to make sure port on the server is accessible.

Before test your C program, make sure the communication is OK between servers by third party application. For example, make an echo server in linux by `ncat -l 2000 -k -c 'xargs -n1 echo'` on port 2000.

It highly recommended change Port from 8080 to another one (for example 8192). 8080 is used with some third party applications.

Comment: Thank you really much! It works now :)) The firewall one is important

Answer (score 2):

The host used by the client is hardcoded:

```
servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
```

You can change the host into the code to reach another computer, or you can read it from command line to have a more flexible use.