# Cannot create connection to my mysql database in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, mysql

i am quiet new here and i've got a question.
I searched through the internet to solve my problem, but i didn't found an answer for this problem.

I want to create a Entry in my MySQL Database from a android device. I censored the IP Adress and the password for this post.

MySQL Version Server: 8.0.21
MySQL Version Connector: 8.0.21

Code for this:

```
package de.kggaming.missingpartner;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class Database {
    public static void sendBugreport(String bugtext){
        try{
            Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://ip_adress:3306/missingpartner","missing_partner","password");
            Statement stmt=con.createStatement();
            stmt.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO missingpartner.bugreport (bug) VALUES ("+bugtext+")");
            con.close();
        }catch(SQLException e){
            System.out.println(e);
            System.out.println("SQLException: " + e.getMessage());
            System.out.println("SQLState: " + e.getSQLState());
            System.out.println("Erro: " + e.getErrorCode());
            System.out.println("StackTrace: " + e.getStackTrace());
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }

}
```

Error:

```
I/System.out: java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server.
    SQLException: Could not create connection to database server.
    SQLState: 08001
    Erro: 0
    StackTrace: [Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement;@7041e90
```

I hope you can help me with this problem.

Comment: Did your phone (host of your app) and PC (host of mysql server) in a same range? Can see each other? Check with ping to ensure that!

Comment: Sorry for the late Answer, i ping checked and they can ping each other.

Comment: Read this answer maybe helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63243958/2527458 specially check your firewall.

Comment: I will check it out tomorrow. Thanks for your help